# Can I use the unlist function in a dataframe?

Tags: r, list, function, dataframe

I was working with a list containing the words from a text and the tags classifying them. I was supposed to restore an old letter, and to do this i needed to extract only the words in a vector, so instead of using sapply, i did this:
`words <- unlist(data.frame(letter)[1,], use.names = FALSE)`
It appeared to work, but the auxiliary professor said that doing this was a problem, since you can only use unlist in lists, so I fixed it, but in the end the results were the same.
PS: I know that using sapply is more efficient, i just didn't remember the function, I'm just curious to know if you can use unlist in other objects

Comment: Data frames are lists - just with more requirements. Run `is.list()` on a data frame.

Comment: You might also be interested in `unname()`

Answer (score 1):

As @Gregor notes, `data.frame`s are lists. Consider the following example:

```
df <- data.frame(Col1 = LETTERS[1:5], Col2 = 1:5, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
is.list(df)
#[1] TRUE
```

Therefore, you can use `lapply` on a `data.frame` to perform column-wise operations:

```
lapply(df,paste0, collapse = "")
#$Col1
#[1] "ABCDE"
#$Col2
#[1] "12345"
```

You have to be careful, however, when subsetting a `data.frame`, as you may not get a list depending on the method you use.

```
df["Col2"]
#  Col2
#1    1
#2    2
#3    3
#4    4
#5    5

is.list(df["Col2"])
#[1] TRUE

df[,"Col2"]
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5

is.list(df[,"Col2"])
#[1] FALSE

is.list(df[["Col2"]])
#[1] FALSE

is.list(df$Col2)
#[1] FALSE

is.list(subset(df,select = Col2))
#[1] TRUE
```

To my knowledge, however, subsetting whole rows always returns a list.

```
df[1,]
#  Col1 Col2
#1    A    1

is.list(df[1,])
#[1] TRUE

is.list(subset(df,1:5 == 1))
#[1] TRUE
```

We can use the `dput` function to view a text representation of the underlying structure of a single row:

```
dput(df[1,])
#structure(list(Col1 = "A", Col2 = 1L), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")
```

As we can see, even the single row is clearly a list. Therefore, we can reasonably `unlist` that row just as we would any list that is not also a `data.frame`.

```
unlist(df[1,], use.names = FALSE)
#[1] "A" "1"

unlist(list(Col1 = "A", Col2 = 1L), use.names = FALSE)
#[1] "A" "1"
```

Comment: Thanks - I think that's all from me for today ;)